# Recommended explicit sharing declaration for inner classes

Tags: sharing, security-review, inner-class

In our last **Salesforce Security Review** we have faced an issue related to the ommitted sharing declarations of inner classes acting as a wrapper.

We have passed this review for years so I guess some new kind of criteria must have been included recently.

These inner wrapper classes are not accessing data anyhow so I wanted to know which would be the recommended sharing declaration (probably `with sharing` or `inherithed sharing`) for them in order to pass the  **Salesforce Security Review** or, if it would be enough to report them as False Positives.

Comment: Related question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270571/do-i-need-to-define-sharing-for-inner-classes), I prefer `inherited sharing`, `with sharing` also would be fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question: [Do I need to define sharing for inner classes?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270571/do-i-need-to-define-sharing-for-inner-classes)

I prefer `inherited sharing`, `with sharing` also would be fine though.

> if it would be enough to report them as False Positives.

No, it's better to have small number of false positives for the security team to review.